# Switching from SQLite3 to Postgresql in the midst of development to accommodate Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I've already done a certain amount of work on an application and I am approaching the implementation for thinking sphinx and search functionality.  TS needs either mySQL or Postgresql db to run, so I am looking to switch my development to Postgresql.

There are many great resources that help you switch away from SQLite3 at the creation of a new rails app like here:
http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/postgres-and-rails-for-mysql-people/ and here: http://www.funonrails.com/2011/03/getting-started-with-rails-3-postgres.html

But these only cover using Postgresql from the absolute beginning.

I initially gave it a shot by installing postgresql on my local machine and the gem

`gem 'pg', :require => 'pg'`

and by changing my `database.yml` file to accommodate postgresql with the hookups to local host, username, password and adapters.  However, this didnt work and I assume its because by not starting with postgresql from the beginning, it didnt install a number of files it needs to.

Is there a good way to make a switch in the middle of development or would it be too messy and would starting over be preferred (which wouldnt be too bad, but not ideal.  And on a different note, I've heard its better to develop with the same type of db that you will deploy with.  Though I could take guesses as to why, anybody care to elaborate why this is preferred?)

Also, being a first time postgresql user (and rails newb), it looks like developing with postgresql is a bit more complicated than sqlite3's built in functionality.  Is the switch suggested?  Or should I find a way around it and stick with sqlite3?

Comment: Does PostgreSQL work at all? (Can you connect to a database with psql or with pgAdminIII?) You're better off switching now than 3 days before deployment.

Comment: @Catcall -- I can connect to a database with the SQL shell (psl) command prompt and I can launch pgAdminIII and modify dbs.  I know relatively nothing about SQL commands/setup, so I'm at that early thrashing stage; trying to get my barrings.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want to develop on PostgreSQL and then deploy on Sqlite3? This won't work.

These two are very different kinds of storage engines. Sqlite is just a convenient library for storing data and accessing it using some subset of SQL. Postgres is a full featured database server - it needs to be installed, needs an user for itself, works as a service, preferably on a dedicated physical computer. Postgres is very powerful, fast and reliable but also needs a lot of learning to tame it.

These two storage engines use different dialects of SQL. A query which works in one  would often fail in another, or do something subtly different, or be terribly slow.

It is not better to develop with the same storage engine that you deploy with — **it is the only way**.

Comment: No, I mean that I have been developing with sqlite3, but would like to switch my development db over to postgres, which I will also use for deployment.  I have been giving myself a crash course through the postgresql documentation and am eagerly looking for some other tutorials to do with postgres and rails development.

Comment: You wrote in your question: "I've heard its better to develop with the same type of db that you will deploy with. Though I could take guesses as to why, anybody care to elaborate why this is preferred.". This made me think that you want to do just this.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
sqlite3 development.sqlite3 .dump | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W database-development
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances of being screwed by surprise becomes less when your development & deployment is on same platform ;) So its always good to work with same db rather than facing probs later